# Prove that $\int_a^b f(x)dx=\int_{\alpha}^{\beta}f(\varphi(y))\varphi'(y)dy$

Tags: real-analysis, proof-verification

Let $f:[a,b]\to\mathbb R$ continuous and $\varphi:[c,d]\longrightarrow  [a,b]$ a surjective function in $\mathcal C^1([c,d])$. I denote $\alpha,\beta\in [c,d]$ such that $a=\varphi(\alpha)$ and $b=\varphi(\beta)$. I want to prove that

$$\int_a^b f(x)\mathrm dx=\int_{\alpha}^{\beta}f(\varphi(y))\varphi'(y)\mathrm dy$$

**This is my proof:**

Let $x=\varphi(y)$. Then $\mathrm dx=\varphi'(y)\mathrm dy$, and thus
$$f(x)\mathrm dx=f(\varphi(y))\varphi'(y)\mathrm dy.$$

When $x$ traverses $[a,b]$, $\varphi(y)$ traverses $[\alpha,\beta]$, therefore $$\int_a^b f(x)\mathrm d x=\int_\alpha^\beta f(\varphi(y))\varphi'(y)\mathrm dy.$$

It looks a little bit ad-hoc, do you think it's correct ?

Comment: an idea is to use the fundamental theorem of calculus. Since $f$ is continuous then it has an antiderivative $F$. So, the LHS is equal to $F(b)-F(a)$. Similarly, the RHS is equal to $F(\varphi(\beta))-F(\varphi(\alpha))=F(b)-F(a).$

Comment: I know, I just want to do if my proof is correct.

Comment: Using $dx$ as a formal object is suspicious, especially on the early calculus courses. Can you explain precisely why $dx = \phi'(y) dy$?

Comment: because $\frac{dx}{dy}=\varphi'(y)$

Comment: @RicK no, it is not a proof.

Comment: why it is not ?

Comment: The problem is that $dx$, or $\frac{dx}{dy}$ have only symbolic meaning. In particular, multiplying both sides by $dy$ does not make sense (neither does the expression $\phi'(y) dy$) until you introduce an algebraic structure involving the differentials. Such notation is only a helpful tool, and the point of this theorem is to prove that we can actually use it that way.

Comment: I guess variable change is taught as he proceeded, even before students are told about Jacobians or exterior product...

Comment: You use u substitution to prove u substitution.

Answer (score 1):

Here is how you make @Joe Aaron's comment more precise.

Let $F(x)$ be an antiderivative for $f$ (you could construct one if you needed that) and compute $\frac{d}{dx} F(\phi(x))$ and note that $F \circ \phi$ is an antiderivative for $f(\phi(x))\phi'(x)$. From there you just use the fundamental theorem of calculus.